# Copy and Paste in linux terminal

Tags: linux

How to do Copy and Paste in Linux CLI? 
I want to copy the path of the file and paste it in another Linux command. But every time I have to type the whole path again and again. It's frustating.

Comment: learn about pwd command

Comment: If you have a mouse. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610538. I you don't http://nmrwiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_copy/paste_text_in_the_UNIX_terminal

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for informing me. @jww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ultimately depends on your terminal and display server setup (X11 in most cases), but you can try these two things:

1. Often you can simply select the text to be copied with your mouse (without pressing any keys) and paste by pressing the middle mouse button (or pressing the scroll wheel).
2. If that doesn't work, try selecting with your mouse, then press `SHIFT-CTRL-C` to copy and `SHIFT-CTRL-V` to paste. Notice the extra `SHIFT` here. `CTRL-C` without `SHIFT` does something else entirely and would send an interrupt signal to the currently running process.

Alternatively, you can use some tool like [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip). E.g. on ubuntu do `apt-get install xclip`. Then you can copy to your clipboard, e.g. by doing

```
echo "Hello World" | xclip
```

and paste with

```
xclip -o
>>> Hello World
```

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on. It is sometimes helpful to suggest a site where the question may be on-topic.