# pasting into CentOS terminal

Tags: copy-paste

How do I copy text from windows10 to centos9?

I tried ctrl+c in windows and then pasting in Centos terminal with ctrl+v, ctrl+shift+v, and mouse right click then paste, but all didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy and Paste in linux terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475963/copy-and-paste-in-linux-terminal)

Comment: I think that this isn't quite the correct location for this question, it might be better asked on either [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), you might also want to add the centos and/or linux tag

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Comment: I can't delete the question : «You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it.»

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are copying  if it's a text file it might be an issue with your OS.
to ease your stress why not use free program WinSCP. You can also transfer data from Windows to Linux servers via SCP.